# Flutter Coding Strategy on Similar Pages

Tags: flutter, dart, design-patterns

I want to develop an app. And the app contains 2 section. Teamleader and staff. So they are different from each other but also they include similar,same and different widgets. For example there's a widget that teamleader can add staff. So which strategy or path should i follow. Should i create views for each of them (staff_home_view, teamleader_home_view) or create just one page or follow any other strategy. And my question is not limited only views also controllers,services and all the things.

Answer (score 0):

You could create different pages for team leaders and staff. But create a common widget if both of them share the same UI.

If the UI is only a little different, you can pass a variable and display the small update in the widget as per that passed variable. (suppose you have passed the `role = teamLeader or staff`)